# Figure out if code is even executing in sails.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sails.js

I've been attempting to work with Sails.js. Unfortunately, I'm beginning to think that it's just not stable enough to be used at all.

This is strange because there seemed to be quite a bit of hype for this framework. Basically, I am just trying to figure out if my code is even running.

I've created a user controller that looks like this.

```
class UserController
    find: (req, res) ->
        sails.log.error("find")

    create: (req, res) ->
        sails.log.error("create")

    update: (req, res) ->
        sails.log.error("update")

    destroy: (req, res) ->
        sails.log.error("destroy")


module.exports = UserController
```

When I originally call sails lift i receive the following.

```
error: find
error: find
```

However, when I load the page my methods don't seem to be called. I don't get anything logged out.

How do I get sails to call my functions as it claims it would with the REST blueprints on?

Comment: try to use console.log instead..

Comment: Does the same. Executes when it's loading the controllers hook but never runs again after that.

Comment: check your routes.. are they configured properly.. blueprint are only activated when you have a model and a controller with same name i.e `api/models/Foo.js` & `api/controllers/FooController.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just being a coffee-script problem. All solved now. Sails is much more pleasant to work with without it now.